# With Npgsql reader.GetString is causing an exception instead of returning data

Tags: .net, vb.net, npgsql

Npgsql is returning an exception, when SQL Shell (psql) is returning text for the same query .

Background:

I have a PostgreSQL database loaded with GEOIP data from MaxMind.

The table definitions can be viewed here:
https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/importing-databases/postgresql?lang=en

Problem

The following query, when run in SQL Shell (psql) returns the proper value, of "France" (without the quotes) in one row as expected:

```
select country_name from geoip2_network net left join geoip2_location location on ( net.registered_country_geoname_id = location.geoname_id ) where network >> '89.185.38.196';
```

(The IP address shown above is for the Louve Museum in Paris)

However the following (vb.net) code causes an exception at the statement
ReturnValue = reader.GetString(0)

The exception, is "Column 'country_name' is null."

Below is the code, the setup routine is called once when the program loads and appears to be working fine.

The GetCountry function is called many times, but an exception is always thrown as described above.

```
Private conn As NpgsqlConnection

Private Async Sub setupConnectionToMaxMindDatabase()

    Dim connString As String = "Host=localhost;Username=redacted;Password=redacted;Database=MaxMind"

    conn = New NpgsqlConnection(connString)

    Await conn.OpenAsync()

End Sub

Private Async Function GetCountry(IP As String) As Task(Of String)

    Dim ReturnValue As String = ""

    Dim SQLQuery As String = "select country_name from geoip2_network net left join geoip2_location location on ( net.registered_country_geoname_id = location.geoname_id ) where network >> '" & IP & "';"

    Try

        Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand(SQLQuery, conn)

            Using reader As NpgsqlDataReader = Await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()

                While Await reader.ReadAsync()

                    ReturnValue = reader.GetString(0)
                    Console.WriteLine(ReturnValue)

                End While
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

        ReturnValue = "Unknown"

    End Try

    Return ReturnValue

End Function
```

I have also tried using Read (instead of ReadAsync) but it doesn't help.

When I put a breakpoint at the reader.GetString(0) statement, and inspect the data it says the reader has rows (= true) and the field count is 1.

I have also tried adding the columns registered_country_geoname_id and geoname_id to the returned results in the select.  When I do upon inspection the field count goes to 3, as expected, but the country_name still returns null (and the other two values are null as well).

I have also tried GetTextReader(0) but with the same result.

reader.GetFieldType(0).ToString returns System.String (as expected)

Any help / advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:

In an attempt to further break down this problem, I've taken the SQL above (which did a join) and divided it into two separate queries.  The first based on the IP address gets the key that is common between the two tables.  The second used that key to get the country code.

It too should have worked, but indeed what happened is the SQL for first query worked fine, but the SQL for second query did not.

Again however, the SQL for the second query worked fine in SQL Shell (psql).

Here is an example, which should return the text "Spain" in the code, but does not.

```
select country_name from geoip2_location where geoname_id=2510769;
```

Again, this works fine in SQL Shell.

Here is the separated code that does not work.

```
 Dim test = "select country_name from geoip2_location where geoname_id=2510769;"

    Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand(test, conn)

        Using reader As NpgsqlDataReader = Await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()

            While Await reader.ReadAsync()

                Dim dummy As String = reader.GetFieldType(0).ToString

                ReturnValue = reader.GetString(0)
                Console.WriteLine(ReturnValue)

            End While

        End Using

    End Using
```

Also, I've looked at the data in the table, and it is correct - there is a row with the key value I am looking for, and the country_name is 'Spain'.

EDIT 2:

I've noticed locale_code is part of the key, so (even though it should not have mattered much) I also tried:

```
SELECT country_name FROM geoip2_location WHERE (geoname_id=2510769 AND locale_code='en');
```

but I got the same results, worked in SQL Shell (psql) but not in the code above.

Comment: Looks like you are reading a different database from the one used by the SQL Shell

Comment: I only have two databases, the MaxMind database, and the default postgres database.  The connect to the MaxMind database, seems to work ok (code included above) in that is not throwing any errors etc..  Plus, at one point I had key fumbled the password in the code above and I got an exception, after I corrected the password the connect part worked fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're confused. `GetString` gets a `string`. If the specified column is `null` then there's no `string` to get, hence exception. If the data might be `null` then you have to allow for that. Have you looked to see what members that data reader class has and whether any of them pertain to that? It would appear not.

Comment: I haven't looked for the documentation for that third-party provider you're using but the documentation for the `SqlDataReader` class addresses this explicitly: *"No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string.
Call IsDBNull to check for null values before calling this method"*. You should not be asking any questions here that can be answered simply by reading the documentation because you should always read the documentation as part of your own efforts to solve the problem first.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thanks for your comments, but the data in the database table is not null it has a text value.  This was proven out when I ran the query in SQL Shell, and it returned the text value of "France".   In fact, I looked through the whole table, and none of the values for 'country_code' are null.

Comment: Also, I've now down some additional trouble shooting and updated the original post with more information.  I'm still left wondering why this is happening.  I am using vs2022 and .net frameword 4.6.2.  I may upgrade to .net framework 4.8 but that will require additional work due to other components used in the solution.  In any case, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You posted an error message that literally stated that the field was null. The question you asked was why `GetString` was not working and that was why: there was no `string` to get. Why there isn't a `string` to get in the first place when you expect there to be is a different question. What question are you actually asking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250612/discussion-between-rob-and-jmcilhinney).

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I had, by mistake, defined and loaded the two database tables I was working within the default postgre database.

I had also defined the two tables in the MaxMind database, but only loaded one of them.

When I queried the database from my program I queried the correct database and table, but one of the tables had no data in it.

When I queried the database using the SQL Shell I was querying the postgre database in error; and it returned the expected results - as two wrongs in this case made a right.

I feel so silly, espicially as @Steve said "Looks like you are reading a different database from the one used by the SQL Shell" and he was 100% right and I just didn't get it.